# gem install - fatal error: 'ruby/config.h' file not found in Mojave

Tags: ruby, macos, macos-mojave

gem install is failing in MacOs Mojave. Anything that can help me solve this? My ruby version is `ruby 2.3.7p456`.

```
➜ sudo gem install json -v '1.8.3'



current directory: /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.3.0/gems/json-1.8.3/ext/json/ext/generator
make "DESTDIR="
compiling generator.c
In file included from generator.c:1:
In file included from ./../fbuffer/fbuffer.h:5:
In file included from /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.13.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.3/usr/include/ruby-2.3.0/ruby.h:33:
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.13.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.3/usr/include/ruby-2.3.0/ruby/ruby.h:24:10: fatal error: 'ruby/config.h' file not found
#include "ruby/config.h"
         ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
1 error generated.
make: *** [generator.o] Error 1

make failed, exit code 2
```

Answer (score 52, accepted):

### Update 15/03/2021

[According to Apple](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/macos-release-notes/macos-catalina-10_15-release-notes), Ruby won't be included anymore in future versions of the system, so using a Ruby version manager will be the only way to go once this will actually happen.

---

### Original answer

After hours and hours of trial and errors I wanted to go deeper into the reasons of this error and I finally found this that I think is the clean way to go around this issue:

> Catalina (NdMe: I think this started earlier, on Mojave) no longer supports including macOS headers in command line
> tools, they have to be explicitly used through Xcode SDK. You can do
> so by running `gem` through the `xcrun` tool like:
>
> `xcrun gem install <your_gem>`

Quoted from a [Github issue comment](https://github.com/fastlane/fastlane/issues/15183#issuecomment-543844264).

Comment: running Catalina - this fixed failed attempts to run 'gem update' and 'gem install <gems>'

Answer (score 24):

Xcode 12 upgrade messed this up for me.

I installed `ruby` from `brew` and added this to my .zshrc

```
export PATH="/usr/local/opt/ruby/bin:$PATH"
export LDFLAGS="-L/usr/local/opt/ruby/lib"
export CPPFLAGS="-I/usr/local/opt/ruby/include"
export PKG_CONFIG_PATH="/usr/local/opt/ruby/lib/pkgconfig"
```

Comment: Thanks, I had similar issue with xcode 12 update. This approach helped me.

Comment: I had to change the paths to point to my rbenv installation but otherwise it worked. Thanks!

Comment: This solved the problem for Xcode 13.1

Comment: It was helpful also for Xcode 13.2.1, when running commands with sudo didn't help, and removing Gemfile.lock didn't help

Answer (score 13):

If you have the Xcode 10 beta running this might fix it

```
sudo xcode-select -s /Applications/Xcode-beta.app/Contents/Developer
```

Comment: In my case I needed to re-install Xcode command line tools, I think it was because I updated Xcode.
This post gave me the correct hint:
https://github.com/flori/json/issues/255

Comment: Please provide explanations for your suggestion, describing what this command does. Thank you!

Comment: I had a similar issue with Xcode 12.2. This worked for me!

Comment: Confirm, XCode 12 is causing the problem
Switching xcode-select to XCode 11.7 works too.

Comment: Great! This solved my issue installing Jekyll! Could you explain what this command is doing?
PD: I'm using Xcode 12.5.1

Answer (score 12):

In macOS Monterey (in the Beta at least), Ruby (`ruby 2.6.3p62 (2019-04-16 revision 67580)`) is still included but it doesn't seem to work well (`fatal error: 'ruby/config.h' file not found`), so I **installed my own version of Ruby**. You can install ruby manually, but I prefer to use [`rbenv`](https://github.com/rbenv/rbenv), a Ruby version manager.

---

### Install ruby using [`rbenv`](https://github.com/rbenv/rbenv#installation)

- **Install rbenv:** `brew install rbenv ruby-build`

  - `ruby-build` is a plugin for `rbenv` to actually install a ruby version, it provides `ruby install` command.
- **Setup rbenv:** `rbenv init`, (and follow its recommended instructions, for example if you're using zsh, it says add `eval "$(rbenv init -)"` to `~/.zshrc`)
- **Install ruby:** `rbenv install 3.0.1`. [Latest version listed here](https://www.ruby-lang.org/en/downloads/releases/)
- **Do what you came to do:** `sudo gem install cocoapods` or `bundle install`

---

### Or install ruby *manually*:

- **Run** `brew install ruby`
- **Run** `echo 'export PATH="/opt/homebrew/opt/ruby/bin:$PATH"' >> ~/.zshrc` so that this version is used
- **Restart terminal**

---

### `asdf`?

An alternative to `rbenv` is [`asdf`](https://asdf-vm.com/#/), but I find `asdf` a bit complicated to use, since it supports more than just ruby, NodeJS. I would argue it does none of them very ergonomically.

---

*Note:* I have an M1 mac, and it's still working.

Comment: Thanks, Ben. Running Monterey and Xcode 13 Beta 2. Manual install fixed it for me but required some extra exports. From the install:

If you need to have ruby first in your PATH, run:
   -   echo 'export PATH="/usr/local/opt/ruby/bin:$PATH"' >> /Users/[username]/.bash_profile

For compilers to find ruby you may need to set:
   -   export LDFLAGS="-L/usr/local/opt/ruby/lib"
   -   export CPPFLAGS="-I/usr/local/opt/ruby/include"

For pkg-config to find ruby you may need to set:
   -   export PKG_CONFIG_PATH="/usr/local/opt/ruby/lib/pkgconfig"

Comment: Note: I had to run `rbenv global 3.0.2` after setting up `rbenv`
Thanks!

Answer (score 6):

I got into this issue when trying to install fastlane with homebrew. None of the suggestions mentioned earlier helped me. Manually installing the `macOS_SDK_headers_for_macOS_10.14.pkg` fixed it.

```
sudo installer -pkg /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/Packages/macOS_SDK_headers_for_macOS_10.14.pkg -target /
```

Comment: Thank you! All other suggestions here (and on other SO threads) failed. This was the ticket.

Answer (score 2):

I was having this same issue where I could not install native extensions due to a failure when including "ruby/config.h".

I believe the cause of this issue was because I was using the ruby version installed with Homebrew. After upgrading to a new version of Ruby with Homebrew, I saw the following helpful message from Homebrew:

```
ruby is keg-only, which means it was not symlinked into /usr/local,
because macOS already provides this software and installing another version in
parallel can cause all kinds of trouble.

If you need to have ruby first in your PATH run:
 echo 'export PATH="/usr/local/opt/ruby/bin:$PATH"' >> ~/.bash_profile

For compilers to find ruby you may need to set:
 export LDFLAGS="-L/usr/local/opt/ruby/lib"
 export CPPFLAGS="-I/usr/local/opt/ruby/include"

For pkg-config to find ruby you may need to set:
 export PKG_CONFIG_PATH="/usr/local/opt/ruby/lib/pkgconfig"
```

Adding the following lines to my ~/.bash_profile fixed the issue for me:

```
export LDFLAGS="-L/usr/local/opt/ruby/lib"
export CPPFLAGS="-I/usr/local/opt/ruby/include"
```

Answer (score 2):

`xcrun gem install <your_gem>` worked for me, but I had to do it multiple times — every time `bundle install` failed.

The best solution is probably to set the same vars as `xcrun` in your `.zshrc` file. `xcrun env` on my system adds:

```
SDKROOT=/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk
CPATH=/usr/local/include
LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/lib
```

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem after installing Big Sur. I found the file ruby/config.h was not present in the Xcode Packages in the Xcode versions I had installed prior to upgrading. I was able to correct it by uninstalling the Xcode versions and reinstalling them.